# Comparar dados de duas tabelas SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa noite,

Estou estudando consultas SQL e me deparei com um problema em uma consulta, tenho duas tabelas:

Tabela: Produtos

```
+----------------+--------------+--------+
| Codigo         | Produto      | Valor  |
+----------------+--------------+--------+
| 01             | Pipoca       | 5.00   |
| 02             | Refrigerante | 4.50   |
| 03             | Chocolate    | 6.00   |
| 04             | Amendoas     | 18.90  |
| 05             | Macarrão     | 3.69   |
+----------------+--------------+--------+
```

Tabela: Pedidos

```
+----------------+--------------+--------+
| Codigo         | Produto      | Valor  |
+----------------+--------------+--------+
| 01             | Pipoca       | 2.90   |
| 02             | Refrigerante | 4.70   |
| 03             | Chocolate    | 5.80   |
| 04             | Amendoas     | 17.90  |
| 05             | Macarrão     | 4.05   |
| 06             | Batata       | 7.00   |
+----------------+--------------+--------+
```

Preciso fazer uma consulta que me retorne a seguinte tabela:

```
+----------------+--------------+------------+
| Codigo         | Produto      | Diferenca  |
+----------------+--------------+------------+
| 01             | Pipoca       |  2.10      |
| 02             | Refrigerante | -0.20      |
| 03             | Chocolate    |  0.20      |
| 04             | Amendoas     |  1.00      |
| 05             | Macarrão     |  0.36      |
| 06             | Batata       |  7.00      |
+----------------+--------------+------------+
```

Alguem por favor pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respondendo ao teu cenário podes fazer algo deste tipo

```
   select 
    ISNULL(A.codigo,B.codigo), 
    ISNULL(A.produto, B.produto), 
    (ISNULL(B.valor,0) - ISNULL(A.valor,0)) as Valor 
from produtos A  with (nolock) right join pedidos B with (nolock)
ON A.codigo=B.codigo
```

Adicionei também o parametro WITH (NOLOCK) que deves pensar em usar. O comando SELECT permite o uso desta opção NOLOCK, evitando assim os bloqueios com os comandos de INSERT.